# Parameters: [KeyPair] must have values

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to mirror my EC2 instance using cloudformation. Currently, I've been able to create the following JSON using troposphere and I come across the error 'Parameters: [KeyPair] must have values'. I am not sure what this 'values' has to be?

I understand the error but not sure what's the solution.

```
{
    "Outputs": {
        "InstanceAccess": {
            "Description": "",
            "Value": {
                "Fn::Join": [
                    "",
                    [
                        "ssh -i ",
                        {
                            "Ref": "KeyPair"
                        },
                        " ubuntu@",
                        {
                            "Fn::GetAtt": [
                                "MyInstance",
                                "PublicDnsName"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "Parameters": {
        "KeyPair": {
            "Description": "jj",
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::launch"
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
        "MyInstance": {
            "Properties": {
                "ImageId": "< my image id goes here>",
                "InstanceType": "t1.micro",
                "KeyName": {
                    "Ref": "KeyPair"
                },
                "SecurityGroups": [
                    {
                        "Ref": "SecurityGroup"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance"
        },
        "SecurityGroup": {
            "Properties": {
                "GroupDescription": "Allow access to MyInstance",
                "SecurityGroupIngress": [
                    {
                        "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0",
                        "FromPort": "22",
                        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                        "ToPort": "22"
                    },
                    {
                        "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0",
                        "FromPort": "80",
                        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                        "ToPort": "80"
                    },
                    {
                        "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0",
                        "FromPort": "8080",
                        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                        "ToPort": "8080"
                    },
                    {
                        "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0",
                        "FromPort": "443",
                        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                        "ToPort": "443"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your KeyPair parameter should have a valid type. According to the [Parameters](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html) section of the [CloudFormation User Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/), the type for a KeyPair parameter is AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName. So it should look like this:

```
"KeyPair": {
  "Description": "The name of the keypair to use for SSH access",
  "Type": "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName"
}
```

Also, if you declare a key pair name as a parameter in your template, you'll have to pass an existing key pair name as an argument when you create a stack using that template.

Comment: I tried that earlier. I get the following error with your solution: `Parameters: [KeyPair] must have values`

Comment: Fyi, "launch" is the name of my keyPair. Do I have to put that anywhere?

Comment: Not in the template. Your key pair is a parameter, so you will have to pass a valid key pair name as an argument when you create a stack using your template (through the web console or CLI, for instance).

Comment: Sounds good, what do you think I should do about the error `Parameters: [KeyPair] must have values`.

Comment: I successfully created a stack using your template (actually, a slightly modified version to fix the parameter type and to specify an existing VPC to the security group and an existing subnet to the EC2 instance, but that shouldn't matter). Are you sure you are passing a valid key pair name as an argument when you create the stack?

Comment: Your comment helped me! I didn't know we had to pass the values. So thanks about that!

Comment: I was pretty confused about how will it know my keypair name

Comment: Great, I've updated my answer to reflect your feedback.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on the accepted answer, you can add a default value for the parameter.  This would have also resolved the error you were seeing.  If `KeyPair` has a static value, you may prefer a default over passing an argument.  You can still override the default by passing an argument.

```
"KeyPair": {
    "Description": "The name of the keypair to use for SSH access",
    "Type": "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName",
    "Default": "launch"
}
```